# How to find domain of a function?

Tags: functions, relations

I came across a question, where in I was asked to find out the domain of the function

$$f(x)= \sqrt\frac{(1-|x|)}{( 2-|x|)}\;$$

Now I can actually put any values and get an answer out of that function. And according to the textbook I am having with me right now, domain of relation R is nothing but the set of all first elements of the ordered pairs in a relation R from a set A to set B.

But when I went ahead and typed the above function in wolfram alpha, the domain given by them was
{${x \in R : x<-2 ~{\rm or}~ -1\leq x\leq1 ~{\rm or}~ x>2}\;$}. Now why the answer is like this. I did not even tell I am defining relation from $\mathbb{R}\;$ to $\mathbb{R}\;$.

Can anyone explain why domain of the above question is ${x \in R : x<-2 ~{\rm or}~ -1\leq x\leq1 ~{\rm or}~ x>2}\;$ and not $\mathbb{C}-2\;$

Comment: Are you given any more information? I.e., are you looking for the $\textit{maximal}$ domain of the function? Is it assumed that it is a real-valued function?

Comment: Also, you say you can put in any value. What happens if you want to evaluate $f(2)$?

Comment: And what happens when you let $x=3/2$?

Comment: @noam.szyfer The question was just to find the domain and not maximal domain. And yeah I forgot to mention about the f(2). It won't be defined over there. In that case the domain should be C-2. Right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson - when you let x = 1.5, the numerator is negative and denominator is positive and therefore the number under square root is going to be a negative number

Comment: Right. So, what does that say about whether or not $x=1.5$ is in the domain?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, The thing is that, even when I put in the value 1.5, I am going to get an answer, but a complex one.  And my question was, when we are asked to find the domains are we supposed to ignore the domain that gives us answers in complex range?

Comment: The only person who knows the answer to that question, arjun, is the person who wrote the problem in the first place. Usually, these things have some *context*, from which one can tell whether the codomain is meant to be the reals, the complex numbers, or something else, but you aren't giving us any context – "I came across a problem" tells us nothing about what kind of answer is expected. So, I'm making the assumption that the intention is to work in the real numbers, and it appears that Alpha also made that assumption. Continued....

Comment: Now, if you want to know *why* Alpha made that assumption, I'm afraid you'll have to ask Mr Wolfram, not us.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of ambiguity in the question. Apparently, Wolfram Alpha makes some assumptions when giving you the answer that the domain is given by

$$ 
\operatorname{Dom}(f) = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x < -2 \text{ or }-1\leq x\leq 1 \text{ or }2 < x\}.
$$

First of all, if we are not asking for the *maximal* domain, the question is not really well-posed. To define a function, one needs to specify the domain as well, and there are many choices! What I mean is that, e.g., the two functions

$$
f \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}, \quad x \mapsto x^2
$$
and
$$
g\colon[-1,1] \to\mathbb{R} \quad x \mapsto x^2 
$$
are different, since they are defined on different domains. So just giving a formula and asking for *the* domain does not really make sense. We could choose many different sets to be the domain.

So let us assume that the question is actually to find the *maximal* domain. Even that is not enough to be sure what the answer should be, since maybe we want to restrict the domain and the codomain to be a subset of the real numbers. That is what Wolfram alpha is doing here. (In fact, we can only say for sure that it restricts the codomain to be real.) So under the assumption that $\operatorname{Dom}(f) \subseteq \mathbb{R}, \operatorname{Cod}(f) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, the function $f$ is only well-defined if the expression in the squareroot is a non-negative number. (In particular, we must avoid dividing by 0.)

But it is perfectly fine to assume that in fact our domain and / or our codomain (see in particular @Gerry Myerson's comment) is a subset of the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$. In that case, we can make sense of the formula of $f$ also for numbers that make the expression in the square-root a negative real number, or a complex number, in which case the maximal domain would be given by points such that the denominator of $\frac{1-|x|}{2-|x|}$ does not vanish. You already figured out that $x = 2$ is problematic, but there are in fact more points to avoid.

Wherever you found that question there should be mentioned which assumptions are made, or it should be clear from context.

Comment: I think you're making an assumption on a relation between domain and codomain. It's perfectly possible, even if the domain is (a subset of) the reals, for the intended codomain to be the complex numbers. I think Alpha is assuming that both domain and codomain are sets of reals, and it's the assumption on the *codomain* that forces us to Alpha's answer for the domain.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You are right, I updated my answer.